# Problems doing basic math from columns in my query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I've setup the following query in SQL Server 2005. In it I derive two columns `SaveCount` and `FailCount`

What I'm trying to do is add the two together. But no matter what I try it fails:

```
SELECT  
   b.fullName, COUNT(*)as SaveCount,
   (SELECT COUNT(status) 
    FROM dbo.ccp_CUSTOMER_RETENTION_LOG as a, 
         dbo.ccp_users as b with (NOLOCK) 
    WHERE a.ccp_UsersID = b.id 
      AND a.ccp_UsersID = '12341' 
      AND status = 'F' 
      AND a.insertDT between '12-06-13' and '12-11-13' 
   GROUP BY 
      b.fullName) as FailCount, 
   SaveCount + FailCount as 'GTotal' 
FROM
   dbo.ccp_CUSTOMER_RETENTION_LOG as a, 
   dbo.ccp_users as b with (NOLOCK) 
WHERE
   a.ccp_UsersID = b.id 
   AND status = 'S' 
   AND a.insertDT between '12-06-13' and '12-11-13' 
   AND a.ccp_UsersID = '12341' 
GROUP BY 
   b.fullName;
```

It's driving me nuts.

Comment: and your problem is what exactly?

Comment: Add them together - you mean SUM(SaveCount)?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was discontinued with the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (more than **20 years** ago)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this without the subquery.

```
SELECT b.fullName
    ,Sum(Case When STATUS = 'S' Then 1 Else 0 End) AS SaveCount
    ,Sum(Case When STATUS = 'F' Then 1 Else 0 End) AS FailCount
    ,Count(*) As 'GTotal'
FROM dbo.ccp_CUSTOMER_RETENTION_LOG AS a
    join dbo.ccp_users AS b -- WITH (NOLOCK)
    on a.ccp_UsersID = b.id
WHERE a.insertDT BETWEEN '12-06-13' AND '12-11-13' 
    AND a.ccp_UsersID = '12341'
GROUP BY b.fullName;
```

Consider using a modern join syntax. Do not use `With (NoLock)` unless you are certain that you 1) will not receive phantom rows or 2) do not care if you receive phantom rows.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you need to read up about the SQL order of operations which will show you how the compiler actually executes the SQL query that you have writtern.  Check out this [link](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/70-SQL-Query-Order-of-Operations.htm).  You will find that you can not reference aliases in your query (except in the ORDER BY clause).  If you copy and paste the actual derived calculations into your sum, then the query should execute properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT  b.fullName, COUNT(*) as SaveCount,

(SELECT COUNT(status) 
from dbo.ccp_CUSTOMER_RETENTION_LOG as a, 
dbo.ccp_users as b with (NOLOCK) 
where a.ccp_UsersID = b.id 
and a.ccp_UsersID = '12341' and status='F' and a.insertDT between '12-06-13' and '12-11-13' 
group by b.fullName) as FailCount, 


COUNT(*)+
(SELECT COUNT(status) 
from dbo.ccp_CUSTOMER_RETENTION_LOG as a, 
dbo.ccp_users as b with (NOLOCK) 
where a.ccp_UsersID = b.id 
and a.ccp_UsersID = '12341' and status='F' and a.insertDT between '12-06-13' and '12-11-13' 
group by b.fullName) 
 as 'GTotal' 


from dbo.ccp_CUSTOMER_RETENTION_LOG as a, dbo.ccp_users as b with (NOLOCK) 
where a.ccp_UsersID = b.id and status='S' and a.insertDT between '12-06-13' and '12-11-13' and a.ccp_UsersID = '12341' 
group by b.fullName;
```

You cannot refer to the subquery/aggregate result aliases in the same query as where they are calculated. You need to either repeat the subquery/aggregate when adding them together(as above) or encapulsate the query in an outer query where the addition is performed using the aliases.

/Daniel